# How to call a method with argment in an input component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I want to call a method with parameter that return a string.

```
public String MyMethod(Integer param) {
    String xx=......;
    return xx;
}
```

And I want to display this result in `<p:inputText>`. How can I do this? I'm using primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following:

```
private String someField;

public String getSomeField() {
   return someField;
}

public String setSomeField(String input) {
    someField = input;
}
```

Then you can access this property in your `.xhtml` file which contains the `<p:inputText>` like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{nameOfYourManagedBean.someField}" />
```

Alright? I'd still recommend you to read a book or something, since this is **very** basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers,
my classBean contain a reference of anotherClass like this

bean user 
{....
Profils idProfil}

So when I've tried to call beanUser.selectedProfil.nameProfil in p:inputText, it works fine.
Thank's